# Calculating the degree of variability of a continuous variable

Tags: variability

I found the term of "degree of variability" from a academic paper. It seems to be used to determine the cutoff of a continuous variable. The most drastic change point was used as the cutoff. In the picture below, the red line was the so-called degree of variability. I dont know what does it mean and why the inflection point can be used as the cutoff. How to calculate it, any code if possible?

**Reference: Hiromi Nakamura, et al. Genomic spectra of biliary tract cancer. Nature Genetics 2015.**https://www.nature.com/articles/ng.3375#MOESM54

In the legend of the Supplementary Figure S1, it said that "... The most    drastic change point in the mutation rate was chosen for the cutoff to discriminate hypermutated cases from non-hypermutated ones."

[image: DistribuCon of variability in mutaCon rate in this cohort. The most drasCc change point in the mutaCon rate was chosen for the cutof]

Comment: I would use the well known "Change point model" to find the cut-off point.

Comment: I don't think this is standard terminology, so it'd help to link the paper (which either should explain how it's defined or give a reference).